# Flutter - Expandable Listview or Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list view which has to many tiles and it looks unprofessional to show them all cause that I would like to show just the first 2-3 tiles and hide the rest... and with and icon to show them all if necessary
I tried the hole day to do something link that in the picture, but unfortunately I don't find a solution
I hope someone has an idea
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use ExpansionTile() widget, like the following code?

```
ListView(
  children: const <Widget>[
    Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: FlutterLogo(),
        title: Text('One-line with leading widget'),
      ),
    ),
    Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: FlutterLogo(),
        title: Text('One-line with leading widget'),
      ),
    ),
    ExpansionTile(
      leading: FlutterLogo(),
      title: Text('One-line with leading widget'),
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: FlutterLogo(),
            title: Text('One-line with leading widget'),
          ),
        ),
        Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: FlutterLogo(),
            title: Text('One-line with leading widget'),
          ),
        ),
        Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: FlutterLogo(),
            title: Text('One-line with leading widget'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```